# Javascript Return Array of Average Test Results Based on Date

Tags: javascript, arrays, average

Say that I've got this array:

```
testResults = [
    {
        dateCreated: "2014-07-12",
        score: 27.1
    },
    {
        dateCreated: "2014-05-11",
        score: 99.3,
    },
    {
        dateCreated: "2014-07-22",
        score: 88.8
    },
    {
        dateCreated: "2014-07-01",
        score: 33.3
    }
];
```

I want to create a function that:

takes `testResults`, `startDate`, `endDate`, and `interval` as arguments and calculates the average test results and returns an array as a result:

```
calculateTestAverages(testResults, "2014-04-01", "2014-07-30", "month");
```

would return

```
testAverages = [0, 99.3, 0, 49.7]
```

I think for now I want to just create an intermediary 2-D array:

```
intermediaryArray = [ [0], [99.3], [0], [27.1, 88.8, 33.3] ]
```

because calculating the average on this intermediary array will be easy.

What I've got so far does NOT work:

```
// takes a string date and converts it into a Date object.
var convertToDateObject = function(date){
    dateObject = new Date(date);
    return dateObject;
}

// takes a string date and returns the month.
var getMonth = function(date){
    return convertToDateObject(date).getMonth();
}

var calculateTestAverages = function(testResults, startDate, endDate, interval){

    var intermediaryArray = [];

    if( interval == "month" ){

        startingMonth = getMonth(startDate);
        endingMonth = getMonth(endDate);
        maxArrayIndex = endingMonth - startingMonth;

        for (var i = 0; i <= maxArrayIndex; i++){
            intermediaryArray[i] = [];
            for (var month = startingMonth; month <= endingMonth; month++){
                for (var testNumber = 0; testNumber < testResults.length; testNumber++){
                    if ( getMonth(testResults[testNumber].dateCreated) == month ){
                        intermediaryArray[i].push(testResults[testNumber].score);
                    };
                };
            };
        };
    };

    return intermediaryArray;

}
```

I've been stuck on this thing for hours. I think my brain is kinda fried at this point.

Comment: Sorry for `calculateTestAverages(testResults, "04/01/2011", "07/30/2014", "month")` do you mean the date to be `04/01/2014` because otherwise the answer doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: You should check that `convertToDateObject` works as expected. `05/11/2014` can be confused with `11/05/2014`, this date format only depends on where you live. You should use an ISO date format like `YYYY-MM-DD` (or others as explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)).

Comment: I see. From my testing `convertToDateObject` is working as expected, but I will change it to ISODate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer your question first and then explain what went wrong. Don't worry about it, the logic behind your code is absolutely fine. It's just a misplaced *curly brace* i.e. `}`.

Let's look at your nested `for` loops and see how they proceed:

```
 var intermediaryArray = []; //initialized earlier

 ...

 for (var i = 0; i <= maxArrayIndex; i++){
        intermediaryArray[i] = [];
        for (var month = startingMonth; month <= endingMonth; month++){
            for (var testNumber = 0; testNumber < testResults.length; testNumber++){
                if ( getMonth(testResults[testNumber].dateCreated) == month ){
                    intermediaryArray[i].push(testResults[testNumber].score);
                };
            };
        };
    };
```

In the test case that you provide, length of the `intermediaryArray` is 4 which gets calculated perfectly. The outer-most `for` loop runs four times. And for every iteration, you do this part:

```
  for (var month = startingMonth; month <= endingMonth; month++){
        for (var testNumber = 0; testNumber < testResults.length; testNumber++){
            if ( getMonth(testResults[testNumber].dateCreated) == month ){
                intermediaryArray[i].push(testResults[testNumber].score);
            };
        };
    };
```

The code above basically loops from `startingMonth` to `endingMonth` and finds the appropriate elements of `testResulsts` array **in that month** and is supposed to push it to the `intermediaryArray`.

In essence, there should be **one** entry for a specific month that represents an `index` in `intermediaryArray`. However, in your `for` loop for **every** index of `intermediaryArray`, you do this check against **all** the months. Let's do a dry run for `i = 0`:

```
 i = 0
 ----------- 
 startingMonth = 4,
 endingMonth = 7

 month = 4 : Nothing gets pushed into intermediaryArray[0]
 month = 5 : {dateCreated: "05/11/2014",score: 99.3} gets pushed into intermediaryArray[0]
 month = 6 : Nothing gets pushed
 month = 7 : The remaining 3 tests get pushed into intermediaryArray[0]

Ultimately all the results get pushed into intermediaryArray[0] as we did not change i with the month variable
```

This is the reason why you in your final returned `intermediaryArray`, you had all the `testResults` pushed at the end of all the loops.

The workaround is really simple, you initialize the `intermediaryArray` once and then populate the `intermediaryArray[i]` i.e. push to it new elements **every** month. In other words, you loop through the `intermediaryArray` in the `for` loop where you loop through the months because there is a **one-one** correspondence between the elements.

Something like this would suffice :

```
 for (var i = 0; i <= maxArrayIndex; i++){
        intermediaryArray[i] = [];  //Initialize the empty array here based on the size
     };

 for (var month = startingMonth,i=0; month <= endingMonth; month++,i++){
 //Simply update the value of i when you update the value of month. 
 //You don't have to enclose the whole thing into the loop that initialises intermediaryArray

       for (var testNumber = 0; testNumber < testResults.length; testNumber++){
                if ( getMonth(testResults[testNumber].dateCreated) == month ){
                    intermediaryArray[i].push(testResults[testNumber].score);
                };
       };
  };
```

It's good to plan on the constraints that we enforce on `for` loops before coding them. Once you know how the arrays are traversed and the way you store it, it's simply about plugging the right conditions into the `for` loop. Hope it clarifies things and helps you get started in the right direction.